# Checking if the user is logged in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In my application I am restricting some view and the user has to be logged in to view them. One way would be to check on every action if the user is logged in or not. But after a bit of research I found that asp.net MVS supports some global filter rules.

How do we use them? Ideally I would want to call a filter onBeforeAction and check if the user is logged in or not..

Is this a right approach? If yes, then can any body give me an example?

Comment: Add the `Authorize` attribute to your controller or actions.

Comment: You will find code examples and detailed explanation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to add the [`Authorize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) attribute to your controller or action methods. For example:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    //Normal action
    public ActionResult DoSomethingForAnyone() { }

    //Secured action
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult DoSomethingOnlyForAuthorisedUsers() { }
}
```

Alternatively you can secure the entire controller and exclude actions you want to be accessible to anonymous users:

```
[Authorize]
public class SecureController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult DoSomething() { }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult DoSomethingForAnyone() { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your [Authorize] will not work with the custom login. If you are using Form Authentication or other Authentication method than [Authorize] will work smoothly.

For custom login on success set

**FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie([user name], false);**

This will make your [Authorize] attribute to work properly.

And for logout use below statement

**FormsAuthentication.SignOut();**

If you follow the above solution than it will reduce your code as well as valid user check on before Action call.